# Which one is taken care by migrations in EF core, Fluent Api definitions onModelCreating or Attribute Tags in Model class?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

if we have codes in both in onModelCreating, Fluent Api definition codes and class definitions with attribute tags,  which one is taken care by EF Core while creating migrations?

Let me tell by code

Fluent API

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Match>(entity =>
  {
   ............
   entity.Property(e =>e.TeamId).HasColumnName("TeamId").IsRequired();
  });

}
```

Attribute Definition

```
public class Match
{
  ............
  [Required]
   public int TeamId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fluent API has higher priority than attributes, i.e. fluent API will override the attributes.

You can test it by defining different mappings for the same field (one using attributes and one using fluent API) and see which one will be used in migration.

Comment: thanks , but when something is missed in FluentApi , what would it happen in this case , for example   [Required] tag exists in class and FluentApi has not got isRequired...

Comment: @ozziem In that case, `[Required]` attribute will be applied because Fluent API doesn't do anything that overrides it. Also, in your case of `TeamId`, it would be non-nullable anyway since it is of type `int` and non-nullable C# types are configured as non-nullable by EF by default.